# Multiple implicit conversions on custom types not allowed?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

```
class C {
public:
    C() { }
};

class B {
public:
    B(C c) { }
    B() { }
};

class A {
public:
    A(bool b) { }
    A(B b) { }
};

int main() {
    A a1 = true; // bool -> A        is allowed
    A a2 = B();  // B -> A           is allowed

    A a3 = 7;    // int -> bool -> A is allowed
    A a4 = C();  // C -> B -> A      isn't allowed
}
```

Why I can use two-step implicit conversion with `bool` but can't use it with `C`?
What is the general rule describing multistep implicit conversion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no multi-step *user-defined* implicit conversion.

```
int -> bool -> A
```

is allowed because the `int->bool` conversion isn't user-defined.

#### 12.3 Conversions [class.conv]

> 1 Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors
> and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined
> conversions and are used for implicit type conversions (clause 4), for
> initialization (8.5), and for explicit type conversions (5.4, 5.2.9).
>
> 2 User-defined conversions are applied only where they are unambiguous
> (10.2, 12.3.2). Conversions obey the access control rules (clause 11).
> Access control is applied after ambiguity resolution (3.4).
>
> 3 [ Note:
> See 13.3 for a discussion of the use of conversions in function calls
> as well as examples below. —end note ]
>
> **4 At most one user-defined
> conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied
> to a single value.**

Comment: So, there is no other base-defined conversions except `int->bool`?

Comment: @Lescott there are a lot of built-in conversions/promotions. `int->bool` is what you have in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Since this construction is perfectly legal

```
A a4((C()));
```

problem is, that you use copy initization. Really, your example is equal to

```
A a4((A(C()));
```

8.5/16

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The destination type is the type of the object or reference being
> initialized and the source type is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is not a single (possibly
> parenthesized) expression, the source type is not defined.
>
> If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> — Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences
> that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function
> is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is
> chosen through overload resolution (13.3).

13.3.1.4/1

> Under the conditions specified in 8.5, as part of a copy-initialization of an object of class type, a user-defined
> conversion can be invoked to convert an initializer expression to the type of the object being initialized.
>
> Overload resolution is used to select the user-defined conversion to be invoked. Assuming that “cv1 T” is
> the type of the object being initialized, with T a class type, the candidate functions are selected as follows:
> — The converting constructors (12.3.1) of T are candidate functions.
>
> — When the type of the initializer expression is a class type “cv S”, the non-explicit conversion functions of
> S and its base classes are considered.

13.3.3.1/4

> However, when considering the argument of a constructor or user-defined conversion function that is a
> candidate by 13.3.1.3 when invoked for the copying/moving of the temporary in the second step of a class
> copy-initialization, by 13.3.1.7 when passing the initializer list as a single argument or when the initializer
> list has exactly one element and a conversion to some class X or reference to (possibly cv-qualified) X is
> considered for the first parameter of a constructor of X, or by **13.3.1.4**, 13.3.1.5, or 13.3.1.6 in all cases, **only
> standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences are considered.**

Your user-defined conversion (C -> B) is not considered in this case.