# Copy-initialisation and explicit constructor - compiler discrepancy

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, constructor

I've discovered a discrepancy between the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, and gcc-4.8.1 (as provided by ideone.com). Consider the following SSCCE:

```
struct S
{
  int x;
};

class A
{
public:
  int x;
  A(const S& s) : x(s.x) {}
};

class B
{
  int x, y;

public:
  template <typename T> explicit B(const T& t) : x(t.x), y(t.y) {}

  B(const A& a) : x(a.x), y(0) {}
};

int main() {
  S s = {1};

  B b1 = s; // Compiles OK on MSVC++;
            // Fails on gcc - conversion from ‘S’ to non-scalar type ‘B’ requested

  B b2(s);  // Fails on both - Error: y is not a member of S in B::B<S>(const T &)
}
```

I understand why the line `B b2(s);` fails - the `explicit` constructor matches so it's tried; but `t.y` doesn't exist. Fine.

But I can't work out whether MSVC++ is correct in allowing `B b1 = s;`, or whether gcc is correct in rejecting it. MSVC++ is constructing a temporary from `A::A(const S&)`, and using that to initialise `b1` via `B::B(const A&)`; I'm not sure why gcc errors.

Which compiler's right?

(As an after note, if I remove the `explicit` both compilers reject `B b1 = s;` - presumably because the templated constructor is now fair game for the implicit construction of the temporary.)

**Edit:** From the comments, it appears the MSVC++ also rejects the `B b1 = s;` line in Visual Studio 2012, so the consensus seems to be it really is an error. In which case - what is the nature of the error? What does that error message *mean*?

Comment: VS2012 also fails with `B b1 = s;`. I believe the failure is the correct action. Which VS didn't fail?

Comment: Interesting. My version is VS2010, so it could be a fixed bug (which will likely break our code when we upgrade!). I'm still interested to know what's going on, though.

Comment: @egur - what's the error message in 2012?

Comment: It's an error because to construct a B from an S would require two user-defined conversions in a row (S -> A -> B), whereas only one is allowed. VS2010 is probably allowing it.

Comment: @Simple I posted an answer, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong on any details.

Comment: @Chowlett - VS2012: error C2039: 'y' : is not a member of 'S'

Comment: MSVC accepts the two step conversion as a language extension. If you want to disable MS language extensions then compile with the /Za flag. When you do this the example will be rejected by the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stolen from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12847286/1508519), the standard says:

> 12.3 Conversions [class.conv]
>
> 4 At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single value.

You're trying to perform two in one step, `S` which needs to be converted for `B`'s constructor that accepts an `A`, and then another for `A`'s constructor that accepts an `S`. The solution is to first cast `S` into an `A`:

```
B b1 = static_cast<A>(s);
```

Comment: This is plainly correct; but you could argue that `S -> A` to make a temporary, then `A -> B` to copy-initialise are each one user-defined conversion applied to different objects. Also, what is `conversion from ‘S’ to non-scalar type ‘B’ requested` trying to tell me?

Comment: @Chowlett A struct/class is a non-scalar type. I think the error message is confusing.

Comment: MSVC accepts the two step conversion as a language extension.  If you want to disable MS language extensions then compile with the /Za flag.  When you do this the example will be rejected by the compiler.