# Constructing a custom string class in c++ from string literals

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, constructor, c++03

I've recently ran into a very pesky problem working with C++03.
I needed to create a new string class that expands on the abilities of `std::string`, providing additional methods and more convenient handling.
All was going well except for one issue: If some function expected a `MyString` parameter and was given a string literal (i.e. `"Hello"`) it couldn't do the conversion from `const char[6]` into `MyString`, despite the fact that `MyString` has a c'tor that accepts `std::string`.
For example, these lines will work:

```
MyString mStr("Hello");
MyString mStr = "Hello";
```

But this code will not work:

```
void myFunc(const MyString& mStr);
myFunc("Hello");
```

Because `"no constructor exists that can perform the conversion from const char[6] into MyString"`.

Adding a c'tor that accepts `const char *` didn't help solve the problem, and even trying to mark them with `explicit` in different combinations didn't help at all.

After spending quite a few hours on this error, I got to the conclusion that it might not be possible to do such a thing because it may require two implicit conversions which the compiler will not perform, however as I said, adding a c'tor from `const char *` to enable conversion in 1 step didn't change anything. So before I'm giving up on this, do any of you have any ideas if it's even possible to solve this problem?

Comment: Adding a constructor `MyString(const char *)` should definitely work. What error are you getting in this case?

Comment: Can you please show the class and all constructors?

Comment: @rodrigo, Currently the c'tors are:

MyString();
MyString(const char* str);
MyString(const std::string& str);

and the error I'm getting is:
"Error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to MyString'"

Comment: @OmriP: I've just tried a class with those two constructors, and `myFunc("hello")` compiles fine. You should really show us your code.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also show us the *exact*, *complete* and *unedited* build log.

Comment: @rodrigo: it's a code from my job at a big company, so I am not sure if it's possible to show it due to copyright protection issues etc... (despite it being simply a customized string class). However I can tell you it's a class which has just 1 private member of type std::string, and pretty much wraps it in a nice interface and adds some methods, all of which pass through unit tests. The only c'tors are the ones I mentioned, and they simply update the inner string member with the given value.

Comment: One random guess: are your constructors public?

Comment: Impossible to say for certain, but my new guess is that, for some unshown code, you need the copy constructor: `MyString(const MyString &s)` or maybe the copy assignment `operator=(const MyString &s)`.

Comment: @rodrigo I have both of them

Comment: Last resort. Do you have any constructor marked as `explicit`?

Comment: @rodrigo yes, but they're not related to construction from strings, they construct from int, long, etc...

Answer (score 2):

As for `MyString`'s constructor taking `std::string const&`, the compiler can not convert from `const char*` through `std::string` to `MyString`, in order to call `myFunc`, because that's two implicit conversions, while it can do only one. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847272/multiple-implicit-conversions-on-custom-types-not-allowed).

In case of `const char*` being the parameter, [I could not reproduce your erorrs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/438fda04a0353420). In addition, making a constructor `explicit` will do no good here, it will ban even that one implicit conversion that was allowed. [See it here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72309bed10b67aa1).

Comment: I understand, but having 2 different c'tors from const char * and std::string makes the compiler complain about "ambigiousness", and adding "explicit" was my way of trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Again, [not reproduced](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fa16f91ed374da9). Wait, didn't test the two initializations. And, [I just did](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/494f93bf4778ff68).

Comment: @OmriP: if you add `explicit` then your constructor will not be found implicitly. If there is ambiguity because two conversions can be done, then the proper way to solve it is by adding another overload that does not need the conversion.

Comment: @LogicStuff Thanks for the edits. As you can probably tell, I'm new to SO, so I still don't know how to format my text correctly. I have to ask though, why was my question voted down? It's still a very real problem for me...

Comment: Your question is good, formatting is ok. I do edits, so I get a badge :) I don't know who downvoted, but probably it's because your problem could not be reproduced (and you didn't provide MCVE from the beginning). MCVE is really appreciated, if you don't have that, as you can see, you won't get the answer that will work for you.

Comment: @LogicStuff do you think perhaps this problem could be caused by compiler settings? My workplace uses very strict and unforgiving compiler settings, that stop compilation when there is the smallest doubt... I have a feeling this could be the reason why nobody was able to reproduce the problem...

Comment: Yes, the compiler might be behind all this (it's VS after all), but I'm not an expert on that.

Answer (score 0):

Defining constructor with parameter "const char *"(MyString(const char *)) should resolve this issue.