# Can not construct a class from std::function when used inside std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, std-function, stdarray

I want to have an `std:array` of `std::function`, but I want to make sure that all elements of the array are initialized.
For that end I built a wrapper class that takes an `std::function` as a construction parameter.

But when I initialize an array of my wrapper class directly with my function (the one who should be inside `std::function`) it fails to compile.

Here is the problem, distilled:

```
#include <functional>
#include <array>

static void f() {}
using F = std::function<void(void)>;
enum { Count = 4 };

struct C
{
    //To get a compilation error when some
    //  elements of the array are not initialized.
    C() = delete;

    C(F) {}
};

//OK
static const C c {f};

//OK
static const std::array<F,Count> direct
{
    F{f},
    {f},
    f,
    f
};

static const std::array<C,Count> wrapper
{
    F{f},   //OK
    C{f},   //OK
    {f},    //OK
    f       //could not convert 'f' from 'void()' to 'C'
};
```

I tried changing the array to an `std::vector<C>` (although it defeats my whole purpose of using an `std:array` to begin with) and it refuses to compile any of the above initializations.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Multiple implicit conversions on custom types not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12847272/580083).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike `C c = f;` (which is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)), in [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), every element is [copy initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

> Each `direct public base, (since C++17)` array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

That means, the last element of `wrapper`, which is of type `C`, is copy-initialized from `f`; which requiers two implicit conversions. The conversion from the function pointer to `F`, and the conversion from `F` to `C`. Both of them are user-defined conversions, but only one user-defined conversion is allowd in one implicit conversion sequence.

For the same reason `C c = f;` fails either.

You can add explicit conversion. e.g.

```
static const std::array<C,Count> wrapper
{
    F{f},   //OK
    C{f},   //OK
    {f},    //OK
    static_cast<F>(f)
};
```

`static const C c {f};` works because it's [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) and behaves differently with [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). For direct initialization the constructors of `C` will be considered and one of them expects an `F` as parameter, `f` could be converted to `F` then anything is fine; only one user-defined conversion is required here.

(emphasis mine)

> In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must **produce T directly from the initializer**, while, e.g. direct-initialization **expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor**.